# When/where to include my own function library (like common.inc)?

Tags: bootstrapping

When, hence where, should I include my own library of functions that I will use throughout my whole project.

Drupal has it's common.inc that is included in drupal_bootstrap during the fase DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL. I also have a common.inc with functions that I use all the time, in different modules. I want to include this file once so I can use it everywhere without having to include it in each file separatlely.

So what is the right location/hook to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Probably best to put it in it's own custom module, e.g

```
sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule_common
```

and enable it as required.

You can make it a dependency of other modules by adding it to those module's .info file, e.g

```
dependencies[] = mymodule_common
```

You could also use subfolder and standalone file in `sites/all/libraries/common` though the module route is recommended.

Comment: Or as an alternative, the module's weight can be changed:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671308/set-drupal-module-weight

Comment: As I understand it this will still not include the file common.inc, right?

Comment: @Asimov, `common.inc` would be named `mymodule.module` and the common functions would be in there. They could also be added as an include with [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) or similar

Comment: I don't want to use module_load_include everytime I need a function from common.inc. I decided to include the file in the hook_init of a module, that way it will always be included.

Comment: @Asimov If you have the module enabled, then you don't need to manually include it. This answer really is the best way to handle the situation.

Comment: Oke, I understand now. The common.module functions would be accessible everywhere when the module is enabled. What would be better about that solution than to include a common.inc file in hook_init and leave the module itself for things like hook implementations? Also I wonder why Drupal itself is not doing it like this.

Comment: @asimov, can you share the relevant directory structure and code snippets of this solution? I just ran into the same situation where I need to have set of functions that are used across custom modules. Thanks!

Comment: @Randell See my own anser to this question.

Answer (score -1):

As requested by Randell here is my own solution:

- Make a subdirectory in you site directory, call it "includes" (for example).
- Put your file with general functions in this directory (for example common.inc).
- Now, in one of your existing modules (I have a module called 'main', where I do all of the general things) add a hook_init function.
- In this init function you include your general function file, like so:

  ```
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . conf_path() . '/includes/common.inc';
  ```

The common.inc functions will be available throughout your project.

Comment: Altering directory structure is a kind of hacking core. And [hacking core is discouraged](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core).

Comment: In what way is this altering the directory structure of core?

Comment: @Mołot could you please motivate your downvote and tell me why you think I am altering the directory structure of core? Actually this is not the case at all.

Comment: Creating directories outside /sites is altering the directory structure of core, by the very definition. /sites is the only place designed to put custom files into. And each time you assume you know who downvoted you basing on comments, you discourage people to post clarifications on your post. There are 4 people thinking answer by David Thomas is valid, each and every of them might downvote you, but the point is you don't and can't *know* who it was.

Comment: Hi Mołot, I would advise you to read more carefully my solution as I explicitly said to make a sub directory in the site directory. It's not about the down vote but more about you not reading the solution and still commenting on it. My solution might not be your first choice but I think it is better than the one by David Thomas, so that's why I will use it.